# $ | \;\overline{z_1}^{3-\alpha} z_1^\alpha - \overline{z_2}^{3-\alpha} z_2 ^\alpha | \leq C ( |z_1 - z_2 |^2 + |z_2| ^2 )|z_1 - z_2|$?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

I questioned about this inequality before, but how about weaker one:

For $\alpha = 0,1,2,3$, does this inequality always hold for any complex number $z_1, z_2$? $$ | \;\overline{z_1}^{3-\alpha} z_1^\alpha - \overline{z_2}^{3-\alpha} z_2 ^\alpha | \leq C ( |z_1 - z_2 |^2 + |z_2| ^2 )|z_1 - z_2|\;(\text{for some} \;C>0)$$
$\overline{z}$ denotes the complex conjugate of $z$, $C$ : independent of $z_1, z_2$.